# Calling method from another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, methods

how can I call the method `insertItem()` in the fragment1 when I click the fab in the fragment2? so I can add items in the recyclerview in my fragment 1.. BTW I am using `BottomNavigationView` so `findFragmentById` won't work for me.. All I see when I search is `findFragmentById`, but what if in my case I don't have XML implemented `fragment`, I have it added in the layout resources..

CODE FOR MAIN ACTIVITY/SCREENONE

```
package com.example.admin.test2;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class ScreenOne extends AppCompatActivity{


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

    Income incomeFragment = new Income ();
    Expense expenseFragment = new Expense ();
    Savings savingsFragment = new Savings ();
    MainScreen mainFragment = new MainScreen ();
    Charts chartsFragment = new Charts ();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById (R.id.Navbot);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId ()){
                    case R.id.home:
                        getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().setCustomAnimations (R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace (R.id.replaceLayout, mainFragment).commit ();
                        updateStatusBarColor("#77dd77");
                        return true;

                    case R.id.income:
                        getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().setCustomAnimations (R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace (R.id.replaceLayout, incomeFragment).commit ();
                        updateStatusBarColor("#779ecb");
                        return true;

                    case R.id.expense:
                        getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().setCustomAnimations (R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace (R.id.replaceLayout, expenseFragment).commit ();
                        updateStatusBarColor("#ff6961");
                        return true;

                    case R.id.savings:
                        getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().setCustomAnimations (R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace (R.id.replaceLayout, savingsFragment).commit ();
                        updateStatusBarColor("#77dd77");
                        return true;

                    case R.id.chart:
                        getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().setCustomAnimations (R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out).replace (R.id.replaceLayout, chartsFragment).commit ();
                        updateStatusBarColor("#77dd77");
                        return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId (R.id.home);


    }

    public void updateStatusBarColor(String color){// Color must be in hexadecimal fromat
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        }
    }


}
```

CODE FOR FRAGMENT1

```
package com.example.admin.test2;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainScreen extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList <ExampleItem> mExampleList;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public MainScreen() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen, container, false);

        DataHandlers dataHandlers = new DataHandlers();

        try {
            String deTails = dataHandlers.getDetails();
            int aMount = dataHandlers.getAmount();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), deTails + "" + aMount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //TAS DITO KA NA MAG SET TEXT SA MGA TEXTVIEW NG AMOUNT AT DETAILS

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mExampleList = new ArrayList <>();
        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.food, "", "", "ADD EXPENSES"));


        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void insertItem() {
        DataHandlers dataHandlers = new DataHandlers();

        String deTails = dataHandlers.getDetails();
        int aMount = dataHandlers.getAmount();

        mExampleList.add(0, new ExampleItem(R.drawable.food, "Food & Drink", "" + deTails, "₱ " + aMount));
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

}
```

CODE FOR FRAGMENT2

```
package com.example.admin.test2;


import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class Expense extends Fragment {



    public Expense() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    //SPINNER
    Spinner sp1;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    String[] names = {"Food & Drink", "Shopping", "Transportation", "Home", "Bills & Fees", "Entertainment", "Healthcare", "Education", "Beauty", "Others"};
    int[] images = {R.drawable.food, R.drawable.shopping, R.drawable.transportation, R.drawable.home, R.drawable.bills, R.drawable.entertainment, R.drawable.medical, R.drawable.education, R.drawable.beauty, R.drawable.others};

    //DATE PICKER
    private EditText mDisplayDate;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

    //FOR THE ADD ITEM
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    EditText amount;
    EditText detail;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate (R.layout.fragment_expense, container, false);


        //spinner
        sp1 = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.customSpinner);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), names, images);
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);

        //fab onClick - sending values to the recycler view
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabs);
        amount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textAmountt);
        detail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textDetailss);

        final DataHandlers dataHandlers = new DataHandlers();

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = sp1.getSelectedItemPosition();

                //DINAGDAG KO
                dataHandlers.setAmount(Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString()));
                dataHandlers.setDetails(detail.getText().toString());

            }
        });

        //int pos = sp1.getSelectedItemPosition();

        //date picker
        mDisplayDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.datePick);

        mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        year, month, day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                //String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());

                month = month + 1;
                String date = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
                mDisplayDate.setText(date);


            }
        };

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want fragments to communicate with each other. I will explain it briefly, but for more details you can refer this android doc https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

You need to define an interface in your Expense fragment, I am calling it `ExpenseListener`, you can change the method name and parameter according to your need.

```
public class Expense extends Fragment{
    ExpenseListener mCallback;

    public interface ExpenseListener{
        public void onExpenseUpdate(String amount);
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // activity must implement
        // the callback interface. it throws an exception otherwise
        try {
            mCallback = (ExpenseListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement ExpenseListener");
        }
    }
```

Call `onExpenseUpdate()` method in your FAB click listener and have your activity implement the ExpenseListener interface.

```
public class ScreenOne extends AppCompatActivity implements Expense.ExpenseListener{
    @Override
    public void onExpenseUpdate(String text){
        // call method of MainScreen
        mainFragment.insertItem();
    }
}
```

then in the overridden `onExpenseUpdate()` method, you can invoke the method of your 2nd fragment. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Ummm.. how do I call the `onExpenseUpdate()` method in the fab??

Comment: I added `mCallBack.onExpenseUpdate();` to the fab to call the method.. sorry sir, but it did not work for me..

Comment: You can directly call `insertItem` in overridden `onExpenseUpdate` method and notice the mCallback variable in the code. It's a reference to the activity and call `mCallback.onExpenseUpdate` in the fab.

Comment: Did you add `onAttch()` method?

Comment: I don't kow why, but the `onAttach()` method is strikethoughed it says that Overrides deprecated method in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' is this affecting the code somehow?

Comment: I called the method in the overriden `onExpenseUpdate`... I followed the answer that you posted.. And there is nothing happening and the DataHandlers in the mainscreen is not getting the data anymore...

Comment: Ignore the onAttach() deprecated method for now. Probably your fragment is not yet created. Are you getting any errors? Can you try to debug if insertItem is even getting called?

Comment: Try to print something in `onExpenseUpdate` and in `insertItem` and see if it get called.